# R and Vertica connection problems

Tags: r, vertica, rodbc

I can connect R with Vertica, but when I try to get data from Vertica I get the following error message:

```
[Vertica][VJDBC](3580) ERROR: Insufficient privilege: USAGE on SCHEMA 'bi_analysts' not granted for current user
```

This is my code:

```
library(RJDBC)
vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", 
                classPath="my_path/vertica-jdbc-7.0.1-0.jar")

vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://...", 
                         "my_uid", "my_pwd")

myquery= dbSendQuery(vertica, "my_query")
```

I guess I should do something like:

```
query = dbSendQuery(vertica, "SET ROLE bi_analysts")
```

but if I try to do that, I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

ok... solved....
I did this:

```
dbSendUpdate(vertica, "SET ROLE BI_ANALYST")
```

(dbSendUpdate doesn't return any result set!)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this situation make sure you make the roles as default to your user.

**See example here :**

```
ALTER USER user_name DEFAULT ROLE role_name;
```

- this way you don`t need to run set role every time